# Storing the order of videos that are in a playlist

Tags: mysql, database-design, video, playlist

I am working on a simple **video-database with a playlist feature**. In such a playlist, videos can be placed in a user-specified order.

So I thought I assign a `number_in_playlist` to each `video_id`. The problem with this is, if say video 19 is lateron moved to a position between video 2 and 3, then additionally the `number_in_playlist` of all the videos inbetween needs to be updated.

Now that strongly reminds me of **Array vs Linked List**. So I thought a linked list would solve that problem, i.e storing something like `previous_video_id_in_playlist` and `next_video_id_in_playlist` for each video record. However, in that case I am not sure how to fetch (in order) all videos that are in the playlist?

This must be a problem that others have encountered before, so I was wondering if there is a standard recommended solution?

PS: I am using MySQL and I very much prefer short, fast queries (which I think speaks against the linked list solution?)

Comment: You might have this already, but since "video" has a many-to-many relationship with "playlist", you have already created an intersection table, right? Create it first, it might provide some ideas of how to approach this.

Comment: I have a table mapping `video_id` to `playlist_id`, if that's what you mean? And my own solution would be to add another field, `number_in_playlist` to that mapping-table. I was just hoping there might be a better solution (for updating).

Answer (score 1):

If you make your `playlist.number_in_playlist` column a **double**, then you can start by sequencing your videos with whole numbers.  When an item in a playlist is moved to a new position, you set the new `number_in_playlist` value to the (probably fractional) number that is half-way between the preceeding and following videos.  This lets you move videos around for a very long time before you ever have to worry about resequencing your whole playlist.

The trigger for resequencing is when your new calculated is equal to one of your end points (i.e. the same value as the preceeding or following video).  For practical purposes this will happen very, very rarely unless your users spend more time resequencing videos than watching them.

Answer (score 0):

can you not do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM videos
WHERE playlist_id = 1
ORDER BY next_video_id_in_playlist ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the list usually not too long? Is write performance not a problem? In this case I'd just use the number_in_playlist solution. On every write all numbers need to be updated basically.

Linked lists in a relational database smell like they will cause unforseeable problems. Like cycles caused by bugs.

Comment: It's not really a problem, I was just thinking that there might be a better solution. Apparently not.